# primefaces dialog assign html code with JSF EL expressions

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I need to create multiple dialogs inside one jsf page.
These dialogs have the same content: 
To illustrate:

```
     <p:dialog  widgetVar="wd#{interaction.id}" dynamic="true" header="#{interaction.report.reportName}" rendered="#{interaction!=null}"  showEffect="fade" width="600" >
                 <p:panelGrid  id="panel#{interaction.id}" columns="1"  >
                    #{myBean.myValue}
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
```

So i was thinking of creating them dynamically and add the content as html code

`"<p:panelGrid  id="panel#{interaction.id}" columns="1"  >
                        #{myBean.myValue}
                    </p:panelGrid>"`

Is that possible, will the EL expressions be interpreted?